# glmmLasso Various errors stating that NA and missing values present when none in the dataset

Tags: r, mixed-models, lasso-regression

It is my first time using glmmLasso so please excuse me if this is a simple mistake. I am trying to use the function to create a binomial regression with a number of numerical and categorical factors.

A number of posts about similar errors to those I am receiving have been resolved by re-stating the categorical variables levels, but that hasn't worked in my case. My code is as follows

```
clinical$subclinical = factor(clinical$subclinical)
clinical$Teat = factor(clinical$Teat)
clinical$drug = factor(clinical$drug)
clinical$serverity = factor(clinical$serverity)
clinical$Cow = factor(clinical$Cow)
clinical$tubes = factor(clinical$tubes)
clinical$farm = factor(clinical$farm)
clinical$Calfs = factor(clinical$Calfs)
clinical$treatement = factor(clinical$treatement)
clinical$subtreatment = factor(clinical$subtreatment)


library(glmmLasso)

glmmLasso(subclinical ~ as.factor(Teat) + as.factor(drug) + as.factor(serverity) + as.factor(tubes)  + as.factor(farm) + 
            Dry_Off_Days + as.factor(Calfs) + as.factor(treatement) + as.factor(subtreatment) + age + 
            fat_1 + protein_1 + lactose_1 + scc_1 + yield_1 + time_1 + 
            max_flow_1 + conc_fed_1 + fat_2 + protein_2 + lactose_2 + 
            yield_2 + time_2 + max_flow_2 + conc_fed_2 + weight + BCS,
          rnd = list(Cow = ~1),
          data = clinical,
          family = binomial(),
          lambda = 100)
```

I receive the following errors

> Error in if (group.sum[1] == 0 & sqrt(sum(score.beta[1:block[1]]^2)) >  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

> In addition: Warning message:

> In Ops.factor(y, Mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

As a form of trouble shooting I have simplified the model significantly, removing most the variables to see if it was my categorical variables causing the issue,

```
glmmLasso(subclinical ~ Dry_Off_Days +  age + 
            fat_1 + protein_1 + lactose_1 + scc_1 + conc_fed_2 + weight + BCS,
          rnd = list(Cow = ~1),
          data = clinical,
          family = binomial(),
          lambda = 100)
```

but I receive the error

> Error in grad.lasso[b.is.0] <- score.beta[b.is.0] - lambda.b * sign(score.beta[b.is.0]) :
> NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

> In addition: Warning message:
> In Ops.factor(y, Mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Note that there are no NA values in the dataset.

Here is the dput() of a very small random subset of the dataset, that still causes the same issues that I am facing so you can see for yourself, and I'll also [attach the full dataset incase](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4f8qm3xbw55ad4y/badremoved.csv?dl=0) that is of any help. Thanks.

```
structure(list(X = c(205L, 438L, 85L, 536L, 581L, 329L, 431L, 
146L), subclinical = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Clinical", "Subclinical"), class = "factor"), 
    Teat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("LF_", 
    "LH_", "RF_", "RF_LF_", "RH_"), class = "factor"), drug = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("SYNULOX", "TEREXINE", 
    "TERREXINE"), class = "factor"), serverity = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    tubes = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
    "3", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), Cow = structure(c(4L, 
    8L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("IE151549212814", 
    "IE151549232824", "IE151549241281", "IE151549251167", "IE151549282077", 
    "IE151549297861", "IE151828760007", "IE151941680002"), class = "factor"), 
    farm = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "4"), class = "factor"), Dry_Off_Days = c(3.3, 2.733333333, 
    1.433333333, 2.8, 4.1, 2.133333333, 3.566666667, 2), Calfs = structure(c(4L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6"), class = "factor"), treatement = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "10", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    subtreatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("0", "2"), class = "factor"), age = c(7.709589041, 
    5.487671233, 3.18630137, 6.189041096, 4.391780822, 5.101369863, 
    7.802739726, 3.164383562), fat_1 = c(3.9275, 5.5275, 2.6625, 
    3.434, 4.5625, 3.305, 3.416666667, 2.846), protein_1 = c(3.4875, 
    3.8375, 3.36, 3.808, 3.7075, 3.505, 3.603333333, 3.298), 
    lactose_1 = c(4.4725, 4.605, 4.4675, 4.332, 4.8275, 4.67, 
    4.473333333, 4.77), scc_1 = c(2.477, 0.02675, 0.223, 0.58375, 
    0.765, 0.021, 1.681333333, 0.072), yield_1 = c(-1.5413041, 
    7.8806937, 0.8921023, 5.1831993, -21.2273281, -12.5422328, 
    -10.4103572, 1.3659622), time_1 = c(5.3, 7.266666667, 7.2, 
    6.666666667, 6.183333333, 5.566666667, 7.8, 9.216666667), 
    max_flow_1 = c(3.294925926, 0.342321429, 3.821866667, 2.296148148, 
    4.25825, 3.912058824, 0.8695, 3.582333333), conc_fed_1 = c(1.2, 
    2.7, 1.4, 1.9, 0.2, 0.1, 1.2, 1.4), fat_2 = c(4.566666667, 
    5.29, 3.6275, 4.7875, 6.186666667, 4.2275, 6.2, 3.8925), 
    protein_2 = c(3.77, 3.876666667, 3.4525, 3.7925, 3.943333333, 
    3.7825, 3.93, 3.505), lactose_2 = c(4.536666667, 4.563333333, 
    4.5325, 4.38, 4.793333333, 4.285, 4.355, 4.7375), yield_2 = c(1.9431404, 
    -1.4835626, -0.8854283, 4.0142704, -10.7772177, -6.3873432, 
    -5.9222661, 4.7830923), time_2 = c(4.3, 5.1, 6.7, 4.433333333, 
    5.55, 3.983333333, 4.55, 6.65), max_flow_2 = c(2.810375, 
    0.29775, 2.6153, 1.852137931, 2.99804, 2.8799375, 0.834, 
    2.840066667), conc_fed_2 = c(1.2, 2.7, 1.4, 1.9, 0.2, 2.7, 
    1.2, 1.4), weight = c(6.605, 6.16, 5.13, 7.053333333, 5.22, 
    4.813333333, 5.84, 4.596666667), BCS = c(2.125, 3, 2.75, 
    3.5, 3, 2, 3.25, 3)), row.names = c(205L, 436L, 85L, 534L, 
579L, 328L, 429L, 146L), class = "data.frame")
```